# Automated extraction of chess PGN from photos of DGT's Centaur's e-ink display

Tags: computer-vision, chess

The [DGT Centaur](https://www.chesshouse.com/products/dgt-centaur-chess-computer) is a chess e-board that contains a computer and light-up squares, making it an over-the-board chess opponent.

The Centaur has a small e-ink display (photo below) that displays the moves from the game in standard algebraic notation. Since the board itself has no way of exporting the game results, the only way to get a PGN off the device through with manual transcription.

I'm interested in automating this process by creating a program that takes photos of the Centaur's e-ink display as input and outputs a transcription of the moves.

I don't have experience in the space, but this problem seems like it requires some combination of OCR to read the moves, but also a trained model that can identify the icons of each chess piece.

I am interested in any example projects or resources that demonstrate an approach to this problem so I can better understand what's involved. Thank you!

[image]